# Rising the song's key one semitone in the reexposition

Tags: harmony

I have frequently heard in pop music to use the technique described above: to start a song with a melody in a certain key and, after a while, to play again that melody raising the key one semitone.

For example, this is done in the next song (I can not remember right now a better example), where melody starts in the initial key at [0:38](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s-pDIZWDfcE&t=0m38s) and thereafter starts in 
a semitone upper one in [1:17](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s-pDIZWDfcE&t=1m17s):

Has this technique a particular name? Are there any specific rules to use it?

Comment: Oh, great... just add 7 sharps to the current key signature.  Us musicians **love** that.  :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Truck driver gear shift.  Use it if you want to sound trite.  (But sometimes trite is right :-)

Comment: Compulsory for any show with the words "Idol" or "Got Talent" in it ;)